# Visual Studio.NET 2010 Error: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, nuget

I was wondering if you have experienced this vague issue when trying to copy a text in visual studio.net 2010 SP1:

> Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

I've got Git Extensions and NuGet add-ons installed. I've also tried opening vs.net running in administrator mode.

Was wondering if anybody has encountered this issue and what steps have been done to amend it?

Cheers,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have this happen right after installing the MVC4 beta, I was literally using copy/paste is that what you mean? In this case I had to reinstall.

Comment: Thought I could fix this via other means, but will do that; I might have corrupted my core vs.net files. Thanks!

Comment: absolutely, I know it's obnoxious if you have more probs email me